# How to activate a cell consisting of a formula after removing the leading space with Macros

Tags: excel, vba

I want to activate a formula in a cell. The cell gets updated reguarly with new equations and I have a code that removes the leading space before the equal sign. The code for removing the leading space only works for text format so I first convert the cell to text, remove the space and then convert the cell to number. However, my issue is that the formula does not get activated after the leading space has been removed and the cell has been converted into number format.

```
Sub RemoveSpaces()

    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

    ActiveCell.Formula = LTrim(ActiveCell.Formula)

    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"

End Sub
```

So, ny issue is that the that the formula does not get activated after running the macro. However, if I enter the cell and press enter, the formula gets activated. I recorded a macros where I entered the cell and pressed enter but the issue I then face is that the macro always gives me the same answer, even when the formula is different. Below you can see the code I used for that macro.

```
Sub RemoveSpaces()

    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

    ActiveCell.Formula = LTrim(ActiveCell.Formula)

    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"

    Range("C33").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "= 224.02*EXP(-0.013*R[-29]C)-R[-31]C[-1]"
End Sub
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub RemoveSpaces()

    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    ActiveCell.Formula = LTrim(ActiveCell.Formula)
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"

    Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
    Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    DoEvents

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enter the line `Calculate` and it will be the equivalent of pressing F9 in excel.